# Hadoop UI shows only one Datanode

Tags: hadoop

I've started hadoop cluster composed of on master and 4 slave nodes.

Configuration seems ok:

[hduser@ubuntu-amd64:/usr/local/hadoop$ ./bin/hdfs dfsadmin -report](http://pastebin.com/6QfgKMmk)

When I enter NameNode UI (`http://10.20.0.140:50070/`) `Overview` card seems ok - for example total Capacity of all Nodes sumes up.

[image]

The problem is that in the card `Datanodes` I see only one datanode.

[image: Datanode card]

Comment: Which distribution and version of Hadoop are you using? Please check if there error stackTrache reported in log files (NameNode and DataNodes).

Comment: Could you please copy the result of this "hadoop dfsadmin -report" from any hadoop node.

Comment: @ruby `hadoop dfsadmin` id deprecated, you have link in my post to `hdfs dfsadmin -report` result.

Comment: That looks absolutely alright except glitch in UI. Thanks

Comment: have the same issue on hadoop 2.7.3

Comment: Hi, I am too having the same issue in k8s. hdfs dfsadmin -admin shows one datanode only randomly e.g. sometime datanode-0 and sometime datanode-1. Datanodes hostname is different datanode-0,datanode-1 but their name is same (127.0.0.1:9866(localhost)). Can this be the issue? If yes, how to solve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across the same problem, fortunately, I solved it. I guess it causes by the 'localhost'.

1. Config different name for these IP in /etc/host
2. Remember to restart all the machines, things will go well.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the same **hostname** in both datanodes.
In your case both datanodes are registering to the  namenode with same hostname  ie 'localhost' Try with different hostnames it will fix your problem.

in **UI** it will show only one entry for a hostname.

in **"hdfs dfsadmin -report"** output you can see both.

Comment: Hi, I am too having the same issue in k8s. hdfs dfsadmin -admin shows one datanode only randomly e.g. sometime datanode-0 and sometime datanode-1. Datanodes hostname is different datanode-0,datanode-1 but their name is same (127.0.0.1:9866(localhost)). Can this be the issue? If yes, how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

The following tips may help you

1. Check the core-site.xml and ensure that the namenode hostname is correct
2. Check the firewall rules in namenode and datanodes and ensure that the required ports are open
3. Check the logs of datanodes
4. Ensure that all the datanodes are up and running

Answer (score 1):

As @Rahul said the problem is because of the same hostname

change your hostname in **/etc/hostname** file and give different hostname for each host
and resolve  hostname with ip address  **/etc/hosts** file

then restart your cluster you will see all datanodes in Datanode information tab on browser

Answer (score 1):

I have the same trouble because I use `ip` instead of `hostname`, `[hdfs dfsadmin -report]` is correct though it is only one[localhost] in UI. Finally, I solved it like this:

```
<property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.hostname</name>                   
       <value>the name you want to show</value>
</property>
```

you almost can't find it in any doucument...

Comment: Hi, I am too having the same issue in k8s. hdfs dfsadmin -admin shows one datanode only randomly e.g. sometime datanode-0 and sometime datanode-1. Datanodes hostname is different datanode-0,datanode-1 but their name is same (127.0.0.1:9866(localhost)). Can this be the issue? If yes, how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, feels like it's been a time. But still I'd like to share my answer:
the root cause is from hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml:
the xml file has a property named dfs.datanode.data.dir. If you set all the datanodes with the same name, then hadoop is assuming the cluster has only one datanode. So the proper way of doing it is naming every datanode with a unique name:
[image]

Regards,
YUN HANXUAN

Answer (score 0):

Your admin report looks absolutely fine. Please run the below to check the HDFS disk space details.

"hdfs dfs -df /"

If you still see the size being good, its just a UI glitch.

Answer (score 0):

My Problems: I have 1 master node and 3 slave nodes. when I start all nodes by **start-all. sh** and accessing the dashboard of master nodes. I was able to see only one data node on the web UI.

My Solution:

1. Try to stop the Firewall temporary by  **sudo systemctl stop firewalld**. if you do not want to stop your firewalld service then r allow the ports of the data node by
   **sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port{PORT_Number/tcp,PORT_number2/tcp} ; sudo firewall-cmd --reload**
2. If you are using sapretae user for Hadoop in my case I am using hadoop user to manage hadoop daemons then change the owner on your dataNode and nameNode file by. **sudo chown hadoop:hadoop /opt/data -R**

My hdfs-site.xml config as given in image
[image: My hdfs-site.xml config as given in image]

3. Check your daemons on data node by **jps** command. it should show as given in the below image.

jps Output
[image: jps Output]