# Datanode started but not shown in dfsadmin -report

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ubuntu-16.04, hadoop3

I am trying to install Hadoop 3.1.0 into two virtual machines:

The first machine contains one name node and one data node, the second contains one data node.

I followed this article [Install Hadoop 3.0.0 multi-node cluster on Ubuntu](https://gaurav3ansal.blogspot.com/2017/08/installing-hadoop-300-alpha-4-multi.html?showComment=1532165047978#c3579785937813748568). And every goes fine until i executed the start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh commands.

When i run the `Jps` command on Name node it shows the following results:

```
16488 NameNode  
16622 DataNode  
17215 NodeManager  
17087 ResourceManager  
17530 Jps  
16829 SecondaryNameNode
```

And when I run it on the Data node it shows:

```
2306 DataNode
2479 NodeManager
2581 Jps
```

But the weird thing is that when executing `hdfs dfsadmin -report` command it only shows `Live datanodes (1)` which is the local datanode.

I made a lot of searches; I didn't find anything useful.

I tried to:

1. Execute `stop-all.sh`
2. Delete all files in Namenode and datanode directories
3. delete all hadoop related files in temp directory
4. executed `hdfs namenode -format` command

There is a similar question here: [Hadoop UI shows only one Datanode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698184/hadoop-ui-shows-only-one-datanode) In which they suggested to change the hosts name. In my Namenode `/etc/hosts` file contains the following lines:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   hadoop-Namenode
192.168.75.131  hadoop-Namenode
192.168.75.132  hadoop-datanode-1
```

And in the Datanode `/etc/hosts` i have:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   hadoop-datanode-1
192.168.75.131  hadoop-Namenode
192.168.75.132  hadoop-datanode-1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by removing `127.0.1.1` lines from both machines

```
127.0.1.1   hadoop-Namenode
127.0.1.1   hadoop-datanode-1
```

These lines was causing a conflict when trying to resolve the host name.